# What is -(-2,3,4)?

Tags: function-construction, evaluation

I was trying to define a function `f` such that, when its second argument is negative, we have
$$
f(a,b,c,d,\dots,n)=f(a,-b,-c,-d,\dots,-n)
$$
i.e., we reverse the sign of everything except for its first argument. The shortest code I could come up with is

```
f[a_, b__] /; Negative[{b}[[1]]] := -f[a, Sequence @@ Minus /@ {b}]
```

which is admittedly not very clean (is there a better approach?).

But anyway, for fun, my first attempt was

```
f[a_, b__] /; Negative[{b}[[1]]] := f[a, -b]
```

which I didn't really expect to work. Much to my surprise, this code does not throw any errors, but it does not really do what I want:

```
f[1, -2, 3, 4]
(* f[1, 24] *)
```

which means that
$$
f(a,b,c,d,\dots,n)=f(a,-bcd\cdots n)
$$

What is going on here? I thought that `-b` would be interpreted as `-(-2,3,4)` (which, as I expected, throws an error). But `Trace`ing it, it seems that it is interpreted as `-(-2)*3*4`. Why?

Comment: check `-b // FullForm`

Comment: @kglr ugh...${}{}$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
ClearAll[foo]
foo[a_, b_?Negative, c___] := foo[a, -b, Sequence @@ (-{c})]

foo[1, -2, 3, -4, 5, 6]
```

> foo[1, 2, -3, 4, -5, -6]

For something that also works with symbolic arguments you can use `` Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ `` instead of `Negative`:

```
ClearAll[foo2]
foo2[a_, b_?Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ, c___] := foo2[a, -b, Sequence @@ (-{c})]

foo2[1, -r, s, -t, u, v]
```

> foo2[1, r, -s, t, -u, -v]

```
foo2[1, -2, 3, -4, 5, 6]
```

> foo2[1, 2, -3, 4, -5, -6]

**What is happening?:**

```
- b // FullForm
```

> Times[-1, b]

```
3 Sequence[a, b, c]
```

> 3 a b c

Comment: It seems the OP has accepted this answer, but with the way I read it, wouldn’t we want the `-b` to remain `-b`? Everything else I agree with, nice methods and explanation, too!

Comment: @CATrevillian,  OP says when `b` is negative  $f(a,b,c,d,\dots,n) = f(a,-b,-c,-d,\dots,-n)$, 
"i.e., we reverse the sign of everything except for its first argument"

Comment: +1, now I see that, and then the example -(-2,3,4) makes sense now. I suck at reading&&math! Thank you :)