# Turning arguments into exponents

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, symbolic, polynomials, sequence

I'd like to replace every instance of `L[stuff],` e.g.,

```
L[-1,-2,-2]
```

in an expression with `x^(-FromDigits[{stuff}])`, e.g.

```
x^122
```

.
But I'm running into an issue-- I'd like to do this with the code

```
L[-1, -2, -2] /. L[a___] -> x^(FromDigits[-{a}])
```

but this produces

```
2/x^6 + x^4 + x^5.
```

In trouble-shooting, I noticed that while

```
L[-1, -2, -2] /. L[a___] -> {a}
```

produces the output I expected, namely `{-1,-2,-2}`, I found that

```
L[-1, -2, -2] /. L[a___] -> -{a}
```

just produces `{4}` rather than `{1,2,2}`. I must be misunderstanding how Sequence behaves when it shows up in the right side of a Rule since when I try just inputting `-{Sequence[-1,-2,-2]}` I get the expected result `{1,2,2}`. Does anyone see where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: funny, I asked a [very similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/201308/34893) last week, I wonder if its the same issue. Anyway, here is a possible workaround: `L[-1, -2, -2] /. L[a___] :> x^(FromDigits[-{a}])`.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform yup it would appear to be exactly the same issue and my reaction to `FullForm[-b]` was exactly the same as yours lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an explanation of why you get `{4}`. As mentioned above, your problem is the use of [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule) instead of [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed), which means the RHS of the rule evaluates before the rule is used. So, let's see what the RHS of the rule evaluates to:

```
-{a} //FullForm
```

> List[Times[-1,a]]

So, when evaluated, the rule becomes:

```
L[a___] -> {Times[-1, a]}
```

Now, it should be clear what happens. When the rule is applied, `a` gets bound to the sequence `-1, -2, -2`, and so the output (before evaluation) is:

```
{Times[-1, -1, -2, -2]}
```

which evaluates to:

> {4}

Answer (score 6):

It's just a matter of using `RuleDelayed`, or rather `:>` instead of `->`.

```
L[-1, -2, -2] /. L[a___] :> x^(FromDigits[-{a}])
```

> x^122

```
L[-1, -2, -2] /. L[a___] :> -{a}
```

> {1, 2, 2}